# How to achieve text extract on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an article list page. It needs to show some content information about this article.
If I only use:

```
 truncate @article.content,:length=>100
```

It will show some html tag, and doesn't show the real content to the user. I want to find some way to get the text extract from the content, so I want to ask is there some embedded way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `strip_tags` to remove the html tags:

```
truncate(strip_tags(@article.content), :length=>100)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only care about the text content but not the tags, you can do a `strip_tags` on the content first.

docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

1. All strings in RoR3 are sanitized by default converting special characters in html entities.
2. If you want to preserve user presentation data (as the formatting on a blog post) you can use a lib like Nokogiri to validate the HTML truncated, something along the lines.=

   `def html_preserving_truncate(data);
     html = truncate(data, lenght: 100);
     Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html).to_s;
   end`